# EXPECT_CALL of function within same class using c++ & gtest

Tags: c++, googletest, function-call

Lets assume i have class B and it has two functions and one function is calling other:

```
Class B {
virtual void funParent();
virtual void funChild();
};

void B::funChild(){}

void B::funParent()
{
  funChild();
}
===============================================
class MockB : public B 
{
 MOCK_METHOD0(funChild,void()); MOCK_METHOD0(funParent,void());
}    
===============================================
class TestClass : public testing::Test {
..
};

//Test case for checking function call of funChild() in funParent()    
TEST_F(TestClass,testFunParent)
{   
//I want to test function call "funChild" using EXPECT_CALL.   
//EXPECT_CALL(__somePtr__,funChild()).Times(Atleast(1));

//B b;    
//b.funParent();
}
```

I am wondering how do i achieve this, since it is a memeber function of same class.

Comment: Did you mean `mockB.funParent();` without mocking `funParent`

Comment: I recommend posting some normal code that is actually compiling (not code + pseudocode like you did). It will be easier to investigate and more people will be interested in helping you. In your example more than one thing might be wrong.

Comment: I apologize if i was not clear enough. All i want to do is to have Unit test for function "funParent()" in which another function is called. I have also modified original question

Comment: I might be too late for this but for anybody who lands on this question, I found this helpful answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37134347/3975468